# How to add multiple service principals to an AAD group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automation, azure-active-directory

I am facing some problem doing a Azure Bash Script regarding.

I have 3 service principals & I want to add them to a group as members.

For example:

Management Group : { myapp01, myapp02, myapp03 }

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add **multiple** service principals to an AAD group, I ran below bash script in my environment and got **response** like this:

```bash
groupId="groupObjId"
sp_list=("myapp01" "myapp02" "myapp03")

for sp_name in "${sp_list[@]}"
do
    spObjId=$(az ad sp list --display-name "$sp_name" --query '[0].id' --output tsv)

    if [ -n "$spObjId" ]; then
        az ad group member add --group $groupId --member-id $spObjId
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Service Principal with Name: $sp_name (Object ID: $spObjId) added to AAD Group successfully."
        else
            echo "Failed to add Service Principal with Name: $sp_name (Object ID: $spObjId) to AAD Group."
        fi
    else
        echo "Service Principal with Name: $sp_name not found."
    fi
done
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, service principals added as **members** to Azure AD group successfully as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Worked that's i want .

Comment: Can you Look my Another Ticket , if you have a time @Sridevi :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77271706/how-to-create-a-user-managed-identity-assign-to-key-vault-service-bus-by-bas