# How to Create a User-Managed Identity & assign to Key Vault , Service Bus by Bash Script

Tags: bash, azure, automation, azure-active-directory

I am facing some problem to create a Bash Script regrading conditions & I am not work not enough in Bash . Please someone help to do this task

I have a 3 Environment in Azure like Test , Dev & Stage .
I want to create user-managed Identities those 3 environment at the same same by bash Script .
I want to assign user-managed Identity to Key Vault, App services , Service Bus & Event Hub by Basg

For Example:
Test Tenant id : 7a610d29-a29a-4833-b40c-27b6120c3c57
Dev Tenant id :  b6fc9b56-eb3d-4768-92e7-81ac62f8a7d1
Stage Tenant Id: 88501bf2-52be-46fd-b4d6-61967b489177

Someone help me to get of this task .

Thanks
Emmi

Comment: Can I provide the solution for creating user identity and assigning it to resources for only 1 tenant as I do not have 3 tenants?

Comment: Sure You can do that @Rukmini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To create User Managed Identity**, make use of below script:

```bash
resourceGroup="ruk"
location="eastus"
identityName="testrukUI"

az identity create --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $identityName --location $location
```

[image]

User Managed identity created successfully:

[image]

To assign the User Managed Identity to **[Azure Key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-cli)** use the below command:

```bash
az keyvault set-policy --name testrukkvv33 --object-id ObjectIDofmanagedidentity --secret-permissions get list
```

[image]

To assign the User Managed Identity to **[Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/identity?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-identity-assign%28%29)** use the below command:

```bash
az webapp identity assign -g ruk -n testrukwebapp33 --identities [system] "/subscriptions/SubID/resourceGroups/ruk/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/testrukUI"
```

[image]

[image]

To assign user managed identity to Event hub and Service bus **refer** the below MsDocs:

[az eventhubs namespace identity | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/eventhubs/namespace/identity?view=azure-cli-latest)

[az servicebus namespace identity | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus/namespace/identity?view=azure-cli-latest)